# Mongodb update statement: How do i update the json object?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

My object is something like this:

```
[
{
    "_id": "596b088131ea400490897c50",
    "stocks": [
        {
            "product": "596b083831ea400490897c4d",
            "price": 45,
            "stock": 18,
            "limit": 4,
            "_id": "596b088331ea400490897c59"
        },
        {
            "product": "596b082931ea400490897c49",
            "price": 49,
            "stock": 20,
            "limit": 18,
            "_id": "596b088331ea400490897c58"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want to make the price 10 which is 45 right now. So, I am using

```
Store.update ({_id: storeId}, {'$set':"stocks.j.price":req.body.price});
```

where j is a variable for looping through different products in the array stocks and price is being sent in the body of request. But it doesn't seem to update the database. Can someone explain how do i do this?

**EDIT**
I finally found the solution.

```
var {id} = req.params;

id = ObjectId(id);
//console.log(typeof Store);
// const something = _.filter(Store, req.body.stores);
// console.log(something);
Store.find({
    _id: {
        $in : req.body.stores
    }
}, (err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

            var index = _.findIndex(data[i].stocks, {'product' : id});
            console.log(typeof data[i].id);
            var tempId = ObjectId(data[i].id);
            var setModifier = { $set: {} };
            setModifier.$set['stocks.'+index+'.price'] = req.body.price;
            Store.findOneAndUpdate ({"_id": tempId}, setModifier, function (err, documents){
                if(!err){
                    res.send({"status": 202, "message": "Price has updated"});
                }
                else{
                    res.send({"status": 400, "message" : "Error message" });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else{
        res.send({"status": 400, "message" : "Error message" });
    }

  // console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: answer posted and approve it if u like my work

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Gbr7W7

Answer (score 2):

Your Correct query will be like this

```
Store.update ({"_id": storeId,"stocks.price":45}, { $set:{ "stocks.$.price" : req.body.price}});
```

for more update tutorials visit below link

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: I tried this query. But 45 is just an example. It can be any number. Here is my code: https://codeshare.io/Gbr7W7

Comment: u can dynamically give your price to change  instead of 45

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a pair of brackets

Change

`Store.update ({_id: storeId}, {'$set':"stocks.j.price":req.body.price});`

To

`Store.update ({"_id": storeId}, {'$set': { "stocks.j.price":req.body.price } });`

Comment: he want to update particular json element having price 45 not total json array

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. But it isnt working. I can share my code with you if you can help me and find out any silly mistake I am doing.

Comment: Check the database server log, it might give you some explaining why your request is not being executed

Comment: Your code looks ok, check also to make sure `data.stocks` is **not** empty

Comment: No, it is not empty. Still dont know the reason. Have been debugging for over an hour now.

Comment: You have this if block `if(tempProd === id)` does it pass this if test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149351/discussion-between-rachit-and-dummy).